# How to Get error output of Stored procedure Activity in ADF Pipeline

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am trying to log error message and pipeline details to sql table.

if my Stored procedure fails with some reason in pipeline, I am unable to get actual error message to capture.

I also tried to put try catch in my SP, but no use.

Any other method to capture the error details of failed SP activity in ADF

Comment: The new Script activity does that.  See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71793165/adf-iterative-select-output-to-copy-activity/71858876#71858876).  Be aware of the limitations, eg max 5,000 rows and 2MB payload.

Comment: Or just use a Lookup activity?

Answer (score 1):

You can raise the error in procedure in catch block as follows.

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[usp_fail_proc] 
AS BEGIN

BEGIN TRY 
    
    // Script

END TRY

BEGIN CATCH 
    DECLARE @ErrorNumber INT = ERROR_NUMBER()

    DECLARE @ErrorSeverity INT = ERROR_SEVERITY()
    DECLARE @ErrorProcedure NVARCHAR(128) = ERROR_PROCEDURE()
    DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000) = ERROR_MESSAGE()
    DECLARE @ErrorState INT = ERROR_STATE()

    RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage, @ErrorSeverity, @ErrorState)

END CATCH 
END
```

And in ADF error can be accessed in failure path as follows. In the activity connected to the failure path we can extract the error message as
**@{activity('sp').error.message}**

[image]

Comment: This error message showed up when `@{activity('sp').error.message}` was used: 
{"error":{"code":"InvalidRequestContent","message":"The request content is not valid and could not be deserialized: 'After parsing a value an unexpected character was encountered: A. Path 'ErrorMessage', line 4, position 115.'."}}

Comment: The reason could be error message is having some characters which are causing error when trying to parse the message.  Try this @{string(replace(replace(activity('sp').error.message,'"',''''), '\' , '\\'))}

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WqKGC.png)

You can use this: connect the red output of your activity with a stored procedure that will fill an sql table as soon as it is Failed

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).